# /Library/Fonts vs. Font Book

Tags: font, font-book

1. Why are some of the file names in the /Library/Fonts folder, e.g. AppleGothic, missing from Font Book's (top level) font name list?
2. Why are some of the (top level) font names in Font Book, e.g. Arial, missing from the /Library/Fonts folder?
3. There are some font names that appear both in the /Library/Fonts folder as well as in Font Book, but with different spacing, e.g. AmericanTypewriter (/Library/Fonts) vs. American Typewriter (Font Book). Why?
4. Are there any other differences between the filenames in /Library/Fonts and the font names in Font Book that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all stems from how font files have a file name as well as a family name and a full name stored inside the file. The file name is what is seen in Finder when looking at /Library/Fonts, whereas the family name is what is shown at the top level in Font Book (with the added items for the full name shown when you click on the triangle). You can find the full name of a font file from Finder using Get Info.

[image]

This screenshot shows the answer to your point 3. The file is called AmericanTypewriter, but it could be called anything, because the actual font within the file is called American Typewriter and won't be changed by renaming the file.

To find a font file given the font listing in Font Book, right click on the font and choose Show in Finder. This will select all the font files which are used to make up this font face.

[image]

AppleGothic is not missing from the list of fonts in Font Book, it's just at the bottom, out of alphabetical order.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. I'm still confused, though, about fonts such as `Bradley Hand`. Not only is there no file under `/Library/Font` with this name, but also if you go over this fonts' files as revealed in the `Finder` by right-clicking and choosing `Show in Finder` (there's only one such file), and you view the full names of the associated fonts using `Get Info`, you will find that none of the full names match `Bradley Hand`. So which one is the font's name: the one in `Get Info` or the one in `Font Book`? And what the heck is the other name?

Comment: @EvanAad  What is your macos version?  I have Bradley Hand Bold and Arial in my Library/Fonts for 10.11.6 and 10.12.5

Comment: @TomGewecke: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5, namely the latest version ("No Updates Available"). According to `EasyFind`, the only filename in `/Library/Fonts` whose name contains the string 'bradley' (ignoring case) is 'Bradley Hand Bold.ttf'.

Comment: @EvanAad  Are you concerned because Font Book uses the name Bradley Hand with Bold as a sub-item instead of just Bradley Hand Bold.ttf?  Do you really not have Arial.ttf in Library/Fonts?

Comment: @TomGewecke: `Arial` is not an issue. Yes, I am referring to the fact that the file associated with the `Font Book` font `Bradley Hand` is called `Bradley Hand Bold.ttf` and the `Get Info` full name associated with this file is `Bradley Hand Bold`. So which one is the font's name? `Bradley Hand`, as in Font Book, or `Bradley Hand Bold`, as the full name in `Get Info`?

Comment: @EvanAad  If Arial not an issue, then maybe you should delete number 2 from your question?

Comment: @EvanAad  Fonts can have several names, such as  Postscript, Full, Family, and File.  In this case they are BradleyHandITCTT-Bold, Bradley Hand Bold, Bradley Hand, Bradley Hand Bold.ttf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60966/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-tom-gewecke).

Answer (score 0):

1. Apple *used to* sort the font list by placing fonts with 'Foundry names' in their title at the end of the list. So "**Adobe** Garamond", "**ITC** New Century Schoolbook", and "**Apple** Gothic" etc would appear after "Wingdings" in the list.

   However, they now have stopped doing this. (I've just noticed in Big Sur.)
2. `/Library/Fonts` is not the only place where fonts can be stored. There is also `/System/Library/Fonts`, and the similar `Fonts` folder in the user account's Library. Nowadays, all OS-bundled fonts are inside the System font folder, and cannot be modified or removed. Grrr.
3. Fonts have a filename, which is what you see in the Finder, and a 'name' that is used in Font menus. The two can be different.
4. Possibly.